# Laravel: routing not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have downloaded clients project from the internet, and it is programmed in Laravel (also seen by directory structure). I have set up `homestead.yaml`, `hosts`, filled the DB and modified `.env`. I also did a `vagrant provision` and 'composer dump-autoload` once everything was done.

Problem I'm facing is that home route '/' returns `index.html` in root. But `route.php` says different:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
```

I've tried to intentionally modify routes so that they point to controller which doesn't exist, deleting some letters inside `Kernel.php`...anything that would reasonably produce an error, and nothing happens. I still get back what is inside `index.html`. Also there is `index.php` which gets returned after I enter anything after slash inside the url:

/bla

/nlo

/xyz

You get the point...what can be the issue?

I have also tried with `artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Have you also checked to make sure that your DocumentRoot is set to the public directory of your application, and not the root?

Comment: Where do I do that?

Comment: It will be in your homestead.yaml (to: /home/vagrant/folder/project/public) and in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/project.name`

Comment: Oh! What an overlooked issue. It worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a webserver misconfiguration error. The webserver is configured to serve `index.html` with more priority than `index.php`. Relevant configuration can be found at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site`, `.htaccess`, or for nginx `/etc/nginx/sites-available/your-site` just to mention the two most common web servers.

Comment: Other Laravel projects I have open normally, so I guess it is not a server issue. I am on Win10 btw

Comment: It can be if using apache2. This is site-specific configuration. Take a look at `DirectoryIndex` directive. Win10 doesn't matter if you're running vagrant, it's linux anyways.